# Integrating a periodic function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion, periodic-function

I have a periodic function ff:

```
ff := Function[x, Piecewise[{{ff[x - 1], x >= 1}, {2 x, 0 <= x < 1}, {ff[x + 1], x < 0}}]]
```

Plotting it works fine:

```
Plot[ff[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-.5, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But integrating it like this:

```
Integrate[ff[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

What I get is a few of:

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

and a few of:

> $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

And it keeps running until I abort the evaluation. What's the problem? Thanks.

---

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers. To avoid any more confusion, this is the signal I actually have to integrate. It's a bit more complex, and I wanted to know if that's the reason why it won't integrate, that's why I went for the sawtooth signal.

```
s := x \[Function] Piecewise[
  {
  {s[x + 2 Pi], x < -Pi},
  {0, -Pi <= x < -Pi/2},
  {Cos[x], -Pi/2 <=  x <= Pi/2},
  {0, Pi >= x > Pi/2},
  {s[x - 2 Pi], x > Pi}
  }
 ]
```

Plot command:

```
Plot[s[x], {x, -8, 6}, PlotRange -> {{-8, 6}, {-.5, 6}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT 2:

Using this much simpler, "automatically" periodic definition for the signal, there seems to be no problem with integration:

```
s = Function[x, Piecewise[{{0, Cos[x] < 0}, {Cos[x], Cos[x] >= 0}}]]
```

Still doesn't answer the question why Mathematica isn't able to integrate the signal when it's defined like above.

Comment: Do you wish to get the area from this integration?

Comment: FYI [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6nIOh.png) is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. Yes, that would be good. I'm exercising Fourier series, and encountered this problem while calculating a_0 (the constant). The formula would be: `(2/T)*Integrate[ff[t], {t, 0, T}]]`, where T is the period.

Comment: And at least the integration works with `SawtoothWave`. See [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WgY9i.png).

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about this signal? `s := x \[Function] Piecewise[{
    {s[x + 2 Pi], x < -Pi},
    {0, -Pi <= x < -Pi/2},
    {Cos[x], -Pi/2 <=  x <= Pi/2},
    {0, Pi >= x > Pi/2},
    {s[x - 2 Pi], x > Pi}
    }]` This the one I actually have to integrate. Again, plotting works, but integrating it doesn't work at all.

Comment: You should had the second function (and a plot) to your question.

Comment: Small comment: you should define pure functions with `Set` (=) instead of `SetDelayed` (:=). Otherwise I'm baffled why `Integrate` fails on this.

Comment: Thanks @TeakeNutma. And strange, right? I'd have thought so, too.

Comment: Hmm... it might work without it being periodic, as the definition of a_0 (constant) and a_k (cos coefficient) in Fourier series only depend on the graph of one period.

Answer (score 3):

### A fix

For `s`, you could use

```
s = x \[Function] Piecewise[{{Cos[x], -Pi/2 <= Mod[x, 2 π, -π] <= Pi/2}}];

Integrate[s[t], {t, -8, 6}]
(* 5 + Sin[6] *)
```

### The problem

The problem with the original `ff` and `s` is that the function calls itself.  Now consider `ff[t]` or `s[t]`.  None of the conditions will evaluate to `False` so "the `Piecewise` function is returned in symbolic form" (documentation). Then the next bullet in the documentation is a somewhat mysterious line: "Only those $val_i$ explicitly included in the returned form are evaluated."  Normally, in `ff[2.3]` say, only one of the values is evaluated; however, one can test that all of the values are evaluated in the case of `ff[t]`.  That causes `ff[t - 1]` to be evaluated, which leads to `ff[t - 2]`, *ad infinitum* were it not for limits on recursion and iteration.

Here's test function that does no recursion.  We can see that `x` is printed twice, and the value of `fff[x]` contains the evaluated piecewise argument.

```
fff = Function[x, 
  Piecewise[{
   {Print[x]; x - 1, x >= 1},
   {2 x + x, 0 <= x < 1},
   {Print[x]; x + 1, x < 0}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fff[x]
(*
  x
  x
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your function as

```
f[x_] := 2 Mod[x, 1]
```

then

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

yields 5
 (as expect 5 triangles of area 1)

To plot:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. See EDIT in my question.

Comment: I think you'll find that the integral gives 5 :)

Comment: @TeakeNutma thanks! typo...evaluates correctly...thanks for reading post